# How to extract text from excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

having this data in excel cell

```
kerass(xcvbn=2, abcdefg_iD='510863005')
```

having 100000 of records so, how to extract id number using **excel formula** from that excel sheet

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your value is in cell `A2`. Here is a formula to be inserted

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("_iD='",A2)-4),"')","")
```

This means:

- Search for "_iD='"
- Once found, subtract the length of "_iD='" of that location (hence the 4)
- Use the total length of the string, subtracted with location and 4, in order to find where the actual identifier begins
- Take the right part of the string, only the part behind "_id='...'" remains
- In that part, replace "')" by an empty string (otherwise you get "...005')"

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

> `=MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,9)`

The `find` formula finds the first "'" starting position
Assuming all the ID's are 9 digits, the `MID` formula uses the starting pos. from `find` and takes the following 9 digits.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming your text is in cell A2, and that the id is the first 9 characters of the last 11 then this is the simplest I can think of:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,11),9)
```

But if extra characters get added or the ID changes length.

Does have the benefit of being minimalist on functions and low volativity.